# Is there a way for me to simplify these echos?

Tags: bash, shell

I am still learning how to shell script and I have been given a challenge to make it easier for me to echo "Name1" "Name2"..."Name15" and I'm not too sure where to start, I've had ideas but I don't want to look silly if I mess it up. Any help?

I haven't actually tried anything just yet it's all just been mostly thought.

```
#This is what I wrote to start 

#!/bin/bash

echo "Name1"
echo "Name2"
echo "Name3"
echo "Name4"
echo "Name5"
echo "Name6"
echo "Name7"
echo "Name8"
echo "Name9"
echo "Name10"
echo "Name11"
echo "Name12"
echo "Name13"
echo "Name14"
echo "Name15"
```

My expected results are obviously just for it to output "Name1" "Name2" etc. But I'm looking for a more creative way to do it. If possible throw in a few ways to do it so I can learn. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? One Name per line, all on one line, troll SO, have one-liner bash do it?

Comment: Just one name per line please

Comment: If creativity is the main goal how about `base64 -d <<<TmFtZTEKTmFtZTIKTmFtZTMKTmFtZTQKTmFtZTUKTmFtZTYKTmFtZTcKTmFtZTgKTmFtZTkKTmFtZTEwCk5hbWUxMQpOYW1lMTIKTmFtZTEzCk5hbWUxNApOYW1lMTUK` ?

Comment: I couldn't even begin to explain what that is doing

Comment: The weird chain is your expected result encoded in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), an encoding generally used to represent binary data as text. `base64 -d <<< weirdChain` is passing the weird chain to the `base64` tool and asking it to decode it, which displays your expected result

Comment: I'm going to try it and use your explanation when asked, thanks a lot.

Comment: With **GNU Parallel** like this `parallel -k echo Name{} ::: {1..15}`

Comment: "I haven't actually tried anything just yet..." gets a -1.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest (possibly not the most creative) way to do this is to use `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" name{1..15}
```

This relies on bash brace expansion `{1..15}` to have the 15 strings.

Comment: Any solution is welcome, I need a variety of answers anyway

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop

```
for i in {1..15};do echo "Name$i";done
```

Answer (score 1):

A few esoteric solutions, from the least to the most unreasonable :

- base64 encoded string :

  ```
  base64 -d <<<TmFtZTEKTmFtZTIKTmFtZTMKTmFtZTQKTmFtZTUKTmFtZTYKTmFtZTcKTmFtZTgKTmFtZTkKTmFtZTEwCk5hbWUxMQpOYW1lMTIKTmFtZTEzCk5hbWUxNApOYW1lMTUK
  ```

The weird chain is your expected result encoded in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), an encoding generally used to represent binary data as text. `base64 -d <<< weirdChain` is passing the weird chain as input to the `base64` tool and asking it to decode it, which displays your expected result

- generate an infinite stream of "Name", truncate it, use line numbers :

  ```
  yes Name | awk 'NR == 16 { exit } { printf("%s%s\n", $0, NR) }'
  ```

`yes` outputs an infinite stream of what it's passed as argument (or `y` by default, used to automatize interactive scripts asking for [y/n] confirmation). The `awk` command exits once it reaches the 16th line, and otherwise prints its input (provided by `yes`) followed by the line number. The truncature could as easily be done with `head -15`, and I've tried using the `nl` "number line" utility or `grep -n` to number lines, but they always added the line numbers as prefix which required an extra re-formatting step.

- read random binary data and hope to stumble on all the lines you want to output :

  ```
  timeout 1d strings /dev/urandom | grep -Eo "Name(1[0-5]|[1-9])" | sort -uV
  ```

  `strings /dev/urandom` will extract ascii sequences from the binary random source /dev/urandom, `grep` will filter those which respect the format of a line of your expected output and `sort` will reorder those lines in the correct order. Since `sort` needs to have a received its whole input before it reorders it and `/dev/urandom` won't stop producing data, we use `timeout 1d` to stop reading from `/dev/urandom` after a whole day in hope it has sifted through enough random data to find your 15 lines (I'm not sure that's even remotely likely).
- use an HTTP client to retrieve this page, extract the bash script you posted and execute it.

  ```
  my_old_script=$(curl "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818680/" | grep "#This is what I wrote to start" -A 18 | tail -n+4)
  eval "$my_old_script"
  ```

  `curl` is a command line tool that can be used as an HTTP client, `grep` with its `-A 18` parameter will select the "This is what I wrote to start" text and the 18 lines that follow, `tail` will remove the first 3 lines, and `eval` will execute your script.
   While it will be much more efficient than the previous solution, it's an even less reasonable solution because high-rep users can edit your question to make this solution execute arbitrary code on your computer. Ideally you'd be using an HTML-aware parser rather than basic string manipulation to extract the code, but we're not talking about best practices here...